# Integral equations iterates question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $K(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ and that $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)h(x) dx=0$. Let $\psi_0(x)=f(x)$. Show that all iterates equal the first iterate and find a simple formula for the solution.

I'm really struggling picking up the concept of integral equations--and ideas on how to go about about this problem?

Comment: Is the first interation given by $f_1(x) = \int_a^b K(x, y) f(y) dy$?

Comment: I believe so, but I am not positive

Comment: I am just asking for the definition. It could also be something like $f_1(y) = \int_a^b K(x, y) f(x) dx.$. You really need to tell us your definition.

Comment: That's part of my problem approaching this question...it seemed very vague so I wasn't sure what it was really asking. The book does not give much by way of definition--the entire chapter is basically the proof showing the existence of a solution in a linear integral equation. Part of the proof defines $\psi_n(x)$ = $f(x) + \lambda \int_{a}^{b} K(x,y)\psi_{n-1} (y) dy$ , so that could be it